# Google Chrome get rid of --disable-gpu-compositing

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint, gpu

When watching videos on Twitch or Youtube I sometimes notice a lot of CPU usage and videos tend to be laggy on 4k resolution. I discovered in htop, that chrome is started with the `--disable-gpu-compositng` and was wondering if this might be the issue.

I did not find however, where I can get rid of this launch setting.

`chrome://version` lists this under "command line"

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --enable-crashpad --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

I also checked the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file and it lists

`Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U`

under Exec.

In chrome settings the setting "use hardware acceleration when available" is enabled.

Versions:
`Google Chrome  107.0.5304.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
`Linux Mint 20.3 Una \n \l`

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of mine by following the third step mentioned at https://linuxhint.com/enable-disable-gpu-acceleration-google-chrome/

TL;DR - go to `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blocklist` and toggle the value to `Enabled`. Relaunch after making changes.

Go to `chrome://gpu` to verify changes.